# solve a system of nonlinear equations using scipy fsolve (math domain error encountered)

Tags: optimization, scipy

I tried to use Scipy's fsolve to find the answers to a system of two nonlinear equations. 
The two equations are:

```
f1 = math.log(x) + 1. - ((1. + (m - 1)*x) / m) + chi * (1 - x)**2
f2 = math.log(1 - x) - (m - 1)*x + chi*m*x**2
```

`m` and `chi` are constants in this case. The essential goal is to find `x`, `y` that satisfies simultaneously `f1(x) = f1(y)` and `f2(x) = f2(y)`. I know the initial guess for `x`, `y` are `0.3` and `0.99`. Below is my code.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math

# some global variables
m = 46.663
chi = 1.1500799949128826

def binodal_fsolve():
    def equations(p):
        x, y = p
        out = []
        out.append(math.log(x) + 1. - ((1. + (m - 1)*x) / m) + chi * (1 - x)**2 - (math.log(y) + 1. - ((1. + (m - 1)*y) / m) + chi * (1 - y)**2))
        out.append(math.log(1 - x) - (m - 1)*x + chi*m*x**2 - (math.log(1 - y) - (m - 1)*y + chi*m*y**2))

        return out

    initial_guess = [0.3, 0.99]
    ans = fsolve(equations, initial_guess)

    return ans

def test_answers(phiL, phiR):
    def functions(x):
        return math.log(x) + 1. - ((1. + (m - 1)*x) / m) + chi * (1 - x)**2, math.log(1 - x) - (m - 1)*x + chi*m*x**2

    return functions(phiL)[0], functions(phiR)[0], functions(phiL)[1], functions(phiR)[1]

print (test_answers(0.2542983070, 0.9999999274))
# (1.3598772108380786e-09, -1.5558330624053502e-09, -8.434988430355375, -8.435122589529684)
res = binodal_fsolve()
print (res)
```

When I executed the code, I always encountered the math domain error. 
However, if I tried to solve it using MAPLE `fsolve`. I can get the answers `(0.2542983070, 0.9999999274)`.

By plugging these back to the equations, I get `(1.3598772108380786e-09, -1.5558330624053502e-09, -8.434988430355375, -8.435122589529684)` which suggests the answers are correct. 
I don't know how to make scipy fsolve work. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Relatively early in the iteration, `y=1.2733826071980916`, so `1-y` is negative, producing the domain error in `math.log`

Comment: This makes sense to me.  The math domain error is normally either encounter zeros or negative in a square root operation. Any suggestions to impose constraints to it to  obtain the physical meaningful results. we know x and y are within (0,1), non-inclusive. I am not sure why MAPLE fsolve finds the correct answer--only basic commands similar to Scipy fsolve were used.

Comment: MAPLE is a symbolic math language.  The closest thing in Python is `sympy`.  `fsolve` is a purely numeric solver.  I don't see constraint options for `fsolve`, but `minimize` in the same package does have constraint based methods.

Comment: @Chenyang: Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes. This solved my problem. I experimented also with root, i.e. by converting it to an optimization problem but with no success. I guess the key step is the numpy.lib.scimath, rather than the Python default math, which I have no prior knowledge. But yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use the `log` function from `numpy.lib.scimath` that returns a complex number when its argument is negative.

Instead of using `scipy.optimize.fsolve`, use `scipy.optimize.root` and change the method to `lm` which solves the system of nonlinear equations in a least squares sense using a modification of the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm. For more methods, see [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root).

```py
from scipy.optimize import root

import numpy.lib.scimath as math

# some global variables
m = 46.663
chi = 1.1500799949128826

def binodal_fsolve():
    def equations(p):
        x, y = p
        out = []
        out.append(math.log(x) + 1. - ((1. + (m - 1)*x) / m) + chi * (1 - x)**2 - (math.log(y) + 1. - ((1. + (m - 1)*y) / m) + chi * (1 - y)**2))
        out.append(math.log(1 - x) - (m - 1)*x + chi*m*x**2 - (math.log(1 - y) - (m - 1)*y + chi*m*y**2))

        return out

    initial_guess = [0.3, 0.99]
    #ans = fsolve(equations, initial_guess)
    ans = root(equations, initial_guess, method='lm')

    return ans

def test_answers(phiL, phiR):
    def functions(x):
        return math.log(x) + 1. - ((1. + (m - 1)*x) / m) + chi * (1 - x)**2, math.log(1 - x) - (m - 1)*x + chi*m*x**2

    return functions(phiL)[0], functions(phiR)[0], functions(phiL)[1], functions(phiR)[1]

print (test_answers(0.2542983070, 0.9999999274))
# (1.3598772108380786e-09, -1.5558330624053502e-09, -8.434988430355375, -8.435122589529684)
res = binodal_fsolve()
print (res)
```

Which gives the following roots `x` and `y`: `: array([0.25429812, 0.99999993])`.

**The full output**:

```
(1.3598772108380786e-09, -1.5558330624053502e-09, -8.434988430355375, -8.435122589529684)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:401: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
   cov_x: array([[6.49303571e-01, 8.37627537e-07],
       [8.37627537e-07, 1.08484856e-12]])
    fjac: array([[ 1.52933340e+07, -1.00000000e+00],
       [-1.97290115e+01, -1.24101235e+00]])
     fun: array([-2.22945317e-07, -7.20367503e-04])
    ipvt: array([2, 1], dtype=int32)
 message: 'The relative error between two consecutive iterates is at most 0.000000'
    nfev: 84
     qtf: array([-0.00338589,  0.00022828])
  status: 2
 success: True
       x: array([0.25429812, 0.99999993])
```